# Mapping a half-plane to the unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am supposed to find a möbius transformation that maps the half-plane $H = \{z \in\mathbb{C} : Im\ z \geq 1 - Re\ z\}$ onto the unit disc $D(0,1)$. Here is how I tried solving this using the six point formula:

I chose 3 arbitrary points on each of the images boundarys such that: $[H, 1, 2-i, 3-2i]$ and $[D, -1, i, 1]$. Using the six point formula I get the following:

$$\frac{H - 1}{H - (3 - 2i)}/\frac{(2 - i) - 1}{(2 - i) - (3 - 2i)} = \frac{D - (-1)}{D - 1}/\frac{i - (-1)}{i - 1}$$

Solving for $D$ I get that $D = \frac{i(z - (1 - 2i))}{z - 3}$ which can be rewritten as $D = i - \frac{2 - 2i}{z - 3}$.

This transformation can be divided into several transformations as follow:

$z\mapsto z -3$

$z\mapsto 1/z$

$z\mapsto (2 - 2i)z$

$z\mapsto -z$

$z\mapsto z + i$

Now for my question: How do I check that this chain of transformations takes the given half-plane and maps it onto the unit disc? I do not know how what happens when I invert $H$. To be honest, I don't even know if I can do this, but it is the only way I can think of to solve this problem.

Comment: It becomes much simpler if you start with a translation and rotation from $H$ to the right half-plane.

Comment: Translate it by -1 and then rotate it by $\pi /4$?

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is supposed to be a Möbius transformation, which would rule out rotation, wouldn't it?

Comment: Quite the contrary. Every Möbius transformation is a combination of translation, rotation, and inversion.

Comment: What we learned is that Möbius transformations are combined translations, inversions and dilations, where dilations is a scaling and a rotation. Only, I don't think we have used dilations to rotate an image, only scale it. So I am not sure how I would go about that, I will have to look into it.